# Differential equation related to the Schwarzschild metric

Tags: differential-equations, general-relativity

How can one find solutions of the following second-order diﬀerential equation
$$\frac{d^2W}{dr^2}-\frac{1}{r}\frac{dW}{dr}=\frac{C}{W^2}\frac{dW}{dr}$$
with the boundary condition $W(r)\to r^2$ at inﬁnity $r\to\infty$? Here $C$ is some constant.

This equation was derived in http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0394 (The Schwarzschild metric: It's the coordinates, stupid! by Pierre Fromholz, Eric Poisson and Clifford M. Will) while attempting to get the Schwarzschild solution in the Landau-Lifshitz formulation of Einstein field equations. The authors were not able to obtain a solution in the general $C\ne 0$ case.

Comment: Two remarks: First, when $C\not=0$, if one replaces $r$ by $r/C$ in the equation, one can reduce to the case $C=1$, and then consider boundary conditions $W\to r^2/C^2$ as $r\to\infty$. Second, because the equation is invariant under the scaling $(W,r)\to (aW,a^2r)$ for $a$ a nonzero constant, one can exploit this to reduce the equation to a first-order equation for which one can analyze the solutions by phase portrait. (MAPLE actually does give an integrating factor for this equation, but the exact integral is extremely complicated, involving hypergeometric functions and algebraic functions.)

Comment: Note, however, that the authors were able to successfully relate the $C\neq 0$ case with a change of the radial variable (see equation (33) in the paper), and in the process gave a good reason why an explicit/exact solution to the nonlinear ODE is "hard".

Comment: @WillieWong:  I don't know how 'good' their reason was, though.  They didn't even get as far as MAPLE gets in integrating the equation.  From what I saw, their main argument that getting an explicit solution is 'hard' was that, after trying various changes of variables, they couldn't get it into a form in which they could integrate it.  Identifying it as an equation of Abel type is not that helpful since they didn't (apparently) recognize that there is an (implicit) integration involving hypergeometric functions.

Comment: @RobertBryant: I was more wondering why the solutions to this particular equation is interesting at all. At the end of the day it is supposed to help in giving us another parametrization of the Schwarzschild metric. Does knowing the explicit/implicit formulae for $W$ in terms of $r$ actually tell us anything useful geometrically, in addition to the usual presentation of the Schwarzschild metric? I highly doubt it.